# CRC field calculation for CAN 2.0 B

Tags: can-bus

Do you have a practical example on how to calculate the CRC field for CAN 2.0 B?

Comment: Are you wondering what algorithm is used to create the cyclic redundancy check within the CAN message? I would think that is probably not only proprietary, but is different depending on which CAN controller is used. I've not done any work in this realm, so don't know for sure.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks. Does the CAN standard suggest a way to calculate it? Is there a step-by-step calculation example, so I can understand exactly how it works?

Comment: This link to a Bosch CAN spec may be helpful: http://www.kvaser.com/software/7330130980914/V1/can2spec.pdf
You can also find some useful information here: http://www.hackersdelight.org/crc.pdf

Comment: Yes. Can you name one link which satisfies my question. I would be glad to accept it!

Comment: @DavidWinslow I read both already. They do not have any example how to calculate the CRC. Thanks anway

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587766/how-is-a-crc32-checksum-calculated

Comment: That was provided by @DavidWinslow in [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks

Comment: @DavidWinslow Please post the information in the comments as an answer show that we can move this question out of the "Unanswered" category

Answer (score 1):

This link to a Bosch CAN spec may be helpful: http://kvaser.com/software/7330130980914/V1/can2spec.pdf

You can also find some useful information here: http://hackersdelight.org/crc.pdf